# Installing Ansible on Windows

Tags: windows, cygwin, ansible

I'm trying to install Ansible on a Win10 machine.

I've followed the guidance to install cygwin with the required packages: https://ericsysmin.com/2016/07/28/install-ansible-on-windows/

When I run `pip install ansible`, I receive the below error:

```
building 'Crypto.Random.OSRNG.winrandom' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
```

The thing is that I have Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 installed. When checking Programs and Features, it lists `Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x64) - 14.0.23026`.

Any idea what's going on, and why isn't my C++ 14.0 install recognized? I'm running `pip` as administrator, tried both from within the cygwin terminal and regular PowerShell.

Answer (score 2):

After some research I found that a potential problem can be if I have the 32-bit version of Python installed.

After uninstalling the existing version, and installing the 64-bit version, I had to remove the existing 64-bit Visual C++ Redistributable 14.0, too, but after that I could successfully install the Visual C++ Build Tools, and that solved the problem.

Now I have another problem, the installer complains about a syntax error in one of the modules, but that's out of scope for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 users at or beyond the Anniversary update should now leverage the [Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide) which is a fully-working Ubuntu (more distros soon) environment within your Windows 10 environment.

You can "natively" install Ansible in that environment with

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ansible/ansible
apt-get update
apt-get install ansible
```

Comment: You can't mix WSL and native Windows environment. WSL is useless, just a toy.

Comment: I've been using ansible on WSL for 2 years flawlessly. I'd still rather be using linux full-time but it gets the job done.

Comment: Are your usage limited to network? In that case it is same as running inside VirtualBox/etc. If you use files from WSL in native Windows  or in opposite direction - that can be interesting because it is not supported way to work with WSL. Though I am interested to hear details if you care! `apt-get install ansible` much easier then Cygwin ))

Comment: If you work with files within WSL, it'll all have linux line endings and stuff. Just have to configure your editor of choice to _not_ change to windows line endings and everything should stay compatible and happy. I think that's the only thing you really have to worry about when opening files in windows that are to be also used in WSL. :)

I don't use virtualbox when possible because sometimes when working on a laptop it can add to more power usage running that whole second OS in there.

The only big limitation I've found is I can't use more advanced kernel stuff such as Docker of course

Comment: My concern is that you can't mix pipes of different process types and move files to WSL, passing env var, etc. I find those restrictions very limiting to use WSL utilities as toolbox on Windows. For example can you use WSL `ansible` from Windows Vagrant?

Comment: Ansible works under WSL, but so far all attempts to use any of Ansible's Windows (win_) modules, such as win_chocolately, fail. Bummer.

Comment: @ChristopherAugustus I've actually had good luck with this, you just have to install the Pip depends for ansible winrm.

`pip install pywinrm` &
`pip install pywinrm[credssp]`

Comment: @nthieling Please edit your answer and show a chocolatey module being installed as well via a hosts file pointing to windows host, so we can see it end-to-end

Comment: I would but that seems out of scope for the question

Answer (score 0):

If you like to have ansible in Cygwin...

Add pre-packaged dependencies::

```
apt-cyg install curl autoconf automake binutils gcc-core gcc-g++ bcrypt openssh openssl openssl-devel libffi-devel
apt-cyg install python2-pip python2-devel python2-pyasn1 python2-openssl python2-yaml
apt-cyg install python2-paramiko python2-cryptography python2-jinja2 python2-setuptools python2-enum34 python2-idna python2-cffi python2-six
apt-cyg install python2-ipaddress python2-asn1crypto python2-packaging python2-markupsafe python2-appdirs python2-pycparser python2-pyparsing
```

Install `ansible` by `pip`::

pip2 install ansible

Following packages will be compiled from pypi as they are missing in Cygwin::

```
pycrypto
ecdsa
pynacl
```

To prevent `fork` issues close every Cygwin apps and run from `ash`::

```
/usr/bin/rebaseall -v
```